# Event tracking - need the link to open in a new window without being treated as pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Here's the script from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action) { 

try { 
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action]); 
} catch(err){}

setTimeout(function() {
document.location.href = link.href;
}, 2000);
}
</script>
```

`<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">Visit example</a>`

The script suggested by Google Analytics works well but for just one thing, I want the link to open in a new tab or window after 2 seconds without being blocked by popup blocker on major browsers like Chrome and IE etc.

I tried using _blank so that it becomes `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" onClick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">Visit example</a>` but it wouldn't work.

Opening a new window using window.open() within setTimeout() will be treated as pop-up and blocked by pop-up blocker. I don't want the new window (or tab) to be treated as a pop-up.

Everything in the GA code is fine except for the new tab/window I need. Please help.

Thanks and appreciate your time.

S.C.

Comment: Why don't you open the window immediately but set the focus to the main window, then after 2 seconds, focus the new window?

Comment: You mean using self.focus()? I've tried that but it didn't work. Also, I learn that Firefox will only obey requests to raise a window if a security option is set, and it's not set by default. Chrome won't pay attention to focus() requests at all, as far as I can tell. Safari does obey focus() request. Any other suggestion? And please provide the code since I'm not js-savvy. I can only roughly guess what the script does but I can't produce one out on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can trigger a click using jquery library.

- Connect jquery library to your project, e.g.:
- And you should make invisible one link then trigger it:

http://jsfiddle.net/PingOfDeath/5tkAz/2/

```
$( "#link" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Then your html should looks like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com', 'Outbound Links', 'example.com'); return false;">Visit example</a>
<a id="link" href="http://www.example.com" target="blank_" hidden="true">Visit example</a>
```

Comment: Hi PingOfDeath, thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work on both Chrome and IE (I've changed your 'blank_' to '_blank'. If you go to http://jsfiddle.net/5tkAz/ it doesn't work as well when you execute it in the result panel. Any suggestion that works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @S.C. mb you should include your ga.js to the file? :)
well I have updated my fork:
http://jsfiddle.net/PingOfDeath/5tkAz/2/